# Python matplotlib high CPU usage

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using matplotlib to plot a simple data, but when I try to move the graph the CPU usage go to up 25% and I can't move the graph. Here is a code example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x = [1,2,3,4,5]

plt.plot(x)
plt.show()
```

The graph renders fast, but I can't move around the image. Is that behaviour normal in matplotlib ?

Comment: no, it's not normal.

Comment: Very unusual - can you give more details - OS, matplotlib version, python version, running from standard interpreter, IDLE or IPython etc.  And confirm it happens with this minimal example running just on its own - no other GUI code or anything wrapping it.

Comment: I'm using a Arch Linux distro and Python3. python3-matplotlib version 1.4.3-2 running from standard interpreter. The plot works well and cool if I call octave to plot inside python, but matplotlib seems lag even with the 4 line code I've posted.

Comment: Have you tried a [different backend](http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend)?

Comment: After adding matplotlib.use('qt4agg') and installing python-pyqt4, the plot works well ! Thanks !