# matplotlib plot High CPU on mouse over move

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'am starting a plot project using matplotlib. I note that the CPU get up to 50% when I simply moving mouse on the plot. 
Is it normal? Is there some problems with my installation ?

I tested with a simple example, in a Debian 9.6 linux , matplotlib 3.0.3, python3.5

With a more complex plot, I managed to set CPU to 100%.
Fortunately, there is no freeze of the GUI.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(19680801)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

data = np.random.random((512, 512))
im = ax.imshow(data, cmap='jet', interpolation='none', aspect='auto')

plt.show()
```

Comment: You may want to try a [different backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32661173/python-matplotlib-high-cpu-usage)

Comment: It's normal that CPU usage increases when moving the mouse, because the position where the mouse is is shown in the taskbar of the window. This needs some (very small) computation. When I do this, I get ~5% CPU usage with Qt5Agg backend, but of course % is relative, so it depends on how good your computer is.

Comment: I have a 4 core cpu Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7500 CPU @ 3.40GHz. I try with different backend like TKAgg, TkCairo, Qt5Cairo, Qt4Cairo,Qt4Agg, Qt5Agg, but it still the same. Il'will try in a other linux platfom.